# Force WP_Query to work in a local timezone

Tags: wp-query, date, date-time, timezones

I have a template that displays an actual event if we have a today one, or a next future one. The template uses this WP_Query, that compares events date with the actual date:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events', // Tell WordPress which post type we want
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', // We want to organize the events by date    
    'meta_key' => 'event_start_date', // Grab the "start date" field created via a third party plugin (stored in YYYY-MM-DD format)
    'order' => 'ASC', // ASC is the other option    
    'posts_per_page' => '1', // Let's show only one / the first event.   
    'meta_query' => array( // WordPress has all the results, now, return only the events after today's date
        array(
            'key' => 'event_start_date', // Check the start date field
            'value' => date_i18n("Y-m-d"), // Set today's date (note the similar format)
            'compare' => '>=', // Return the ones greater than or equal to today's date
            'type' => 'DATE' // Let WordPress know we're working with date
        )
    )
);

$featured = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This works, but I found a problem. Accordingly to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82094/25187), WordPress sets the PHP timezone to UTC for internal calculations. In my database events date are saved in a "Y-m-d" date format (without time). So, this means that at 2017-08-31 00:01 date/time (24h format) in my local timezone (UTC+2) the WP will compare a saved event date, say 2017-08-31, with 2017-08-30 of his internal UTC timezone (2 hours difference!) and still will display an old event instead of new one in these 2 hours after 2017-08-31 00:00 in my local time. How to solve this?

**UPDATE**

Changed the code as was recommended by @Milo. The problem is solved!

**UPDATE - About duplicate**

Guys, I suppose that for you my question is a duplicate of an existing question that already has a very clear answer, clear for you, but not also for me, as this answer doesn't have any example code. I seen that answer, if you have not noticed, and I put a link to it in my question before you, but this doesn't helped me much. I needed an exact solution for my situation, and @milo provided it for me, so I thank you him!

Comment: the answer you linked has a solution.

Comment: I don't know how to use that solution :(.

Comment: replace `date("Y-m-d")` with `date_i18n("Y-m-d")`

Comment: Tested right now, it works! Thank you very much! BTW, I found that the time discrepancy actually was more than 2 hours. Can't explain this!

Comment: those aren't times, they're timestamps, you should convert your current time to UTC before passing it to `WP_Query`, see http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/01/14/a-story-about-timestamp-and-timezone/

Comment: @tom-j-nowell Does it make any sense to convert my local time to UTC before passing it to WP_Query if WP_Query uses by default the UTC timezone? Probably you means to convert the saved events time? My events takes place in a UTC+2 timezone and their date are saved by events authors accordingly to this timezone as a `meta_key` value (so, not converted to UTC). And they are saved only as a date/day, without time/hours, so how to convert them if, moreover, it is not very clear what is the time discrepancy in my situation? @milo gave me the exact solution and it seems to work, so I am happy.

Comment: the timestamp in UTC represents the moment in time universally, not the what it says on the clocks in the UTC timezone. That's purely a coincidence. WP stores everything in UTC regardless of timezone, and translates to the preferred timezone, so you need to convert to UTC when saving, and then back to UTC+2 when displaying, which is exactly what WP already does. Otherwise there'd be massive confusion when it came to sites that store multiple timezones, or users in multiple timezones. e.g. what happens if a user on holiday in UTC+4 makes a post and there's no conversion?

Comment: @tom-j-nowell I understand this, but I can't convert date/time to UTC when saving, this is made by a third party plugin (mentioned in the code, not in the question). I must to learn how to do this. Anyway, thank you!